# Why does this code not generate a redeclaration Error?

Tags: c, extern, static-variables

Here is an `extern` and a `static` variable with same name. The output prints the static variable a=10. Why is there no syntax error and how would I access extern `a` if needed?

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int a;
static int a=10;

main()
{
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Comment: Archaic compiler?   You should be getting errors for your main.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are you sure? Where does C standard explain the static-after-extern case?

Comment: @AlexD: My comment says nothing about the main subject of the question.  I'm only observing that C99 and C11 both require `int main(void)` or similar.  A compiler that accepts what was in the question is working with the archaic C89 or C90 standard.  That's all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, understood, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The C standard allows the opposite, `extern` after `static`:

> **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**
> ....
>   <sup>3</sup> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.
>
> <sup>4</sup> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a
>   prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or
>   external linkage, ***the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the
>   linkage specified at the prior declaration***. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
>   declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

At the same time it states:

> <sup>7</sup> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external
>   linkage, the behavior is undefined.

BTW, the C++ standard makes it explicit:

> **7.1.1 Storage class specifiers**
> ....
>
> ```
> static int b; // b has internal linkage
> extern int b; // b still has internal linkage
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ```
> extern int d; // d has external linkage
> static int d; // error: inconsistent linkage
> ```

Comment: Thanks and can i get the source link ??

Comment: extern int d; // d has external linkage
static int d; // error: inconsistent linkage

I didnt get this does thi applicable to c++

Comment: @Anjaneyulu "_can i get the source link_" Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/81656 to see where to get the C and C++ standards.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu "_does this applicable to c++_" Yes. (Although my VS 2015 with `/W4` just gives a warning C4211: _nonstandard extension used: redefined extern to static_.)

Comment: Thanks  for you info